# Update one Oracle table from another table

Tags: oracle, join, sql-update, oracle12c

I have data as in below table A. I need to update the Table B as shown.

Table A:

```
fruit   Apple   Newyork,california
fruit   Mango   Newyork,california,Boston
fruit   Grapes  Boston
flowers roses   New york, California
```

Table B

```
fruit   Apple   Newyork
fruit   Apple   California
fruit   Mango   Newyork
fruit   Mango   California
fruit   Mango   Boston
fruit   Grapes  Boston
flowers roses   Newyork
flowers roses   California
```

Please help me with the query to insert/update the data in table B from table A

Comment: Do you mean `insert` Table B? Is it an existing table with rows containing values for fruit or a new table?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle+sql-update+join

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex and connect by.

```
Insert into B
select distinct
t.c1, t.c2,
trim(regexp_substr(t.c3, '[^,]+', 1, levels.column_value))  as c3
from 
A t,
table(cast(multiset(select level from dual connect by  level <= length 
(regexp_replace(t.c3, '[^,]+'))  + 1) as sys.OdciNumberList)) levels
order by c1
```